# AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'StreamListener'

Tags: python, json, twitter, pymongo, tweepy

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.id_str)
        try:
            tweet_collection.insert_one(status._json)
        except:
            pass
  
    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = strem_api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
myStream.filter(track=track)
```

I am using the current version of jupyter notebook. I am getting AttributeError:

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
2     def on_status(self, status):
3         print (status.id_str)

AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'StreamListener'

please help with this

Comment: If you are not using a version of tweepy prior to 4, go with Stream class instead of StreamListener.

Comment: Installing collected packages: oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, tweepy
Successfully installed oauthlib-3.2.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 tweepy-4.10.1. I am using the 4.10.1 version currently but still getting the the error

Comment: Okay, then you need to override the Stream class, not StreamListener.